# What is the difference in the API or features of Watson Tone Analyzer service with standard & premium plan?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, tone-analyzer

I am using the Watson Tone Analyzer service. At the time of service creation, there are two pricing plans - Standard & Premium. Is there any difference in the API or features of the API if the service is created with Premium plan? Does it have any extra support as compared to the Standard plan?

Answer (score 1):

You get complete access to API and features in both standard and premium plans of IBM Watson Tone Analyzer.

The only difference between the two is an additional layer of security provided to the data at rest and during transit that offers added isolation for your data.

Only the lite version has number of API calls limitation as mentioned in the pricing page of tone analyzer here - https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/tone-analyzer

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in actual API features between Standard and Premium plans. On the pricing page it states that "Watson Premium plans offer a higher level of security and isolation to help customers with sensitive data requirements." But specifically what that means is that IBM offers two additional tiers of service over the standard, shared SaaS offering - Premium (a single-tenant virtual environment deployed on Bluemix Shared) and Dedicated (a private cloud deployment built on Bluemix Dedicated).

For pricing specifics, you'd have to contact sales from the pricing page: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/tone-analyzer.html#pricing-block

It basically comes down to your security requirements and weighing them against the additional costs.